# Centralizar Janela Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

Queria saber como faço para quando chamar uma Janela secundaria no Swing ele deixe centralizada com a Janela Principal do programa. No momento, quando eu chamo a ele aparece no canto esquerdo superior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, funcionou de primeira.

Comment: Por nada :D. Se a resposta lhe ajudou marque-a como correta para que possa ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode centralizar um frame através do método **setLocationRelativeTo()**.
Veja esse exemplo:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MeuFRame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame janela = new JFrame("Frame vazio");
        janela.setSize(300,200);
    janela.setVisible(true);
    janela.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    }
}
```

Você pode aprender mais na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) java.Procure (de um control+f) pelo método **setLocationRelativeTo**.